# Separete billing addresses from payment methods

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, billing-address

I have a issue in magento 2 checkout.

**I want to show billing addresses from payment methods in other container**, separate of payment methods. Now the billing addresses are in payment method container, and i don't need this.

How can i handle it?

Please check this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFbrF.png for more info.

Comment: I get the HTML section which handle the billing address from payment method template and I put it into list.html. Each billing address has something like this $parent.getRegion('billing-address-form-[method type]'). It's not working because is needed to adjust also the js, because in the billing address form are some methods called from payment/default.js .. I have to think on how I can separate it.

Comment: @AndreiTodorut Have you completed above task?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya not

Comment: @AndreiTodorut Have you got solution?